# How to unit test functions that use type hinting

Tags: unit-testing, symfony, mocking, phpunit, type-hinting

Lets say I have a class that contains a function that uses type hinting like this:

```
class Testable 
{
    function foo (Dependency $dependency) 
    {

    }
}
```

And I want to unit test this class `Testable` using this code:

```
$dependencyMock = $this->getMockBuilder('Dependency')
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->getMock();


$testable = new Testable($dependencyMock);
```

If I use PHPUnit to create a stub of $dependency and then try to call the function `foo` using this mock (like above), I will get a fatal error that says:

> Argument 1 passed to function foo() must be an instance of Dependency, instance of Mock_Foo given

How can I unit test this function with PHPUnit and still stub `$dependency`?

Comment: show your testcode where you create your mock.

Comment: are you sure `Dependency` is a class that exists? Shouldn't it have a namespace?

Comment: try to use full namespace like \some\name\space\Dependency when you use mocking, it should fix

Comment: Thank you! Using a namespace fixes the error.

Comment: @Shakil you should move your comment to an answer so it may be accepted.

Comment: @StevenScott thanks, moved the comment to answer

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Use full namespace when you use mocking, it will fix the mockery inheritance problem.

```
$dependencyMock = $this->getMockBuilder('\Some\Name\Space\Dependency')
    ->disableOriginalConstructor()
    ->getMock();
$testable = new Testable($dependencyMock);
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I don't think the fact that you need the full namespace was clear in the documentation. Once I saw your post I thought "oh! of course" but I def didn't get that from the documentation.

Comment: For a more robust way to do this in PHP 5.5+ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20446771/how-to-unit-test-functions-that-use-type-hinting/33159534#33159534

Answer (score 21):

The easiest way to use a full namespace in PHP 5.4+ is with the class static method:

```
SomeClass::class
```

So in the OP's example:

```
$dependencyMock = $this->getMockBuilder(Dependency::class)
    ->disableOriginalConstructor()
    ->getMock();
$testable = new Testable($dependencyMock);
```

This makes refactoring with an IDE a lot easier

Comment: This is better than the other answers (in PHP 5.4+). `::class` is the way to go to ensure the correct class is being used

Comment: With this answer, I finally got it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

My explication for the Shakil's answer:

I had the same problem.

Following the symfony2 cookbook, I created a mock of

```
\Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager
```

and my service constructor was:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

/* ... */

public function __construct(EntityManager $oEm)
{
    $this->oEm = $oEm;
}
```

So I created my unit test (following symfony2 cookbook):

```
$entityManager = $this->getMockBuilder('\Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager')
    ->disableOriginalConstructor()
    ->getMock();

$myService = new MyService($entityManager);
```

Then I had the error:

```
Argument 1 passed to MyService::__construct() must be an instance of Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager, instance of Mock_ObjectManager_f4068b7f given
```

First I though that type hinting was incompatible with unit tests, because a mock instance was passed to the constructor instead of an instance of EntityManager.

So after some research, the class **Mock_ObjectManager_f4068b7f** is in fact a dynamic class extending the class of your mock (in my case **Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager**), so the type hinting is not a problem and works well.

My solution was to create a mock of **Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager** instead of **\Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager**:

```
$entityManager = $this->getMockBuilder('\Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager')
    ->disableOriginalConstructor()
    ->getMock();

$myService = new MyService($entityManager);
```

*I am just beginning with unit tests, so you may find my explication evident :p*